# How to allow only deposit in WooCommerce?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the Partial Payment plugin and would like to only allow my customer to Partially pay and not to pay in Full Amount. How do I delete the radio button of "Full Payment" in the Checkout page?

I have tried to edit the CSS with 'visibility: hidden' but nothing changes.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more?? What do you want to achieve? Let user pay half (example) of the total price??? And what about second half?? When do they pay remained half?? Is it kind of security deposit ???

Comment: the user only pay deposit online to place the order and the remaining will be paid as cash on delivery.. so i would like to remove the "pay the full amount" option in the checkout page